# phone gap plugin in cordova project

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

In my project I am trying to open files which are downloaded in my phone using file opener. I my previous project i was doing the same thing using phonegap file opener module installed in my cordova project.
Now I am trying to use the same module in my new project using the command `cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener` or this command `cordova plugin add cordova plugin add https://github.com/antonioJASR/FileOpener.git`
this is the plugin in GitHub https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener
the errors are `Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener.FileOpener` in the first command and `Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova". Please try adding it again.` 
any idea how can i use the plugin in cordova project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the first error because the plugin does not exist on the NPM repository so you can't install it like that. You are getting the second error because the plugin does not contain a `package.json` file and cordova tries to run `npm install` per default for every new plugin. You need cordovas `--nofetch` option to install it anyway since cordova 7.0.0:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/antonioJASR/FileOpener.git --nofetch
```

See the release notes for cordova 7.0.0 [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html) to read more about the `--nofetch` mode.